# Awk to find maximum and minimum from column and store in other column

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

Need your support for below. Please help

If column 5 is INV then only consider column1 and take out duplicates/identical rows/values from column1 and then put minimum value of column6 in column7 and put maximum  value in column 8 and then need to do subtract values of column 7 from column 8 and then plus one to result and store final result in column 9 and column 11.
Also need to ommit/delete column(column5 and column 6) in output file

For example in input file 27AAACH1458C1ZZ is 6 times, but need to consider only 5 rows as one row in column 5 has value REVERSED which we need to be discard(need to consider rows where column 5 has values "INV").

So among 7 rows, in column 6 minimum value will be "IN27201800023182" and maxmimum value will be "IN27201800024289", so need to put minimum in column7 and maximum in column8.

Thereafter need to consider last 8 digits from both column(7 and 8) and subtract column 7 from column 8. Then need to add/plus 1 to subtraction result and store in column 9 and column 11. Need to skip/delete column 5 and column 6 in output file.

```
    a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k
    27AAAC8C1ZZ|042018|||INV|IN27201800023521|||||
    27AAAC8C1ZZ|042018|||INV|IN27201800024289|||||
    27AAAC8C1ZZ|042018|||INV|IN27201800023356|||||
    27AAAC8C1ZZ|032018|||REVERSED|IN27201800022431|||||
    27AAAC8C1ZZ|042018|||INV|IN27201800023400|||||
    27AAAC8C1ZZ|042018|||INV|IN27201800023182|||||
```

output should be

```
a|b|c|d|Min|Max|result|j|result
27AAAC8C1ZZ|042018|||N27201800023182|IN27201800024289|1108||1108
```

Code im trying to find maximum and minimum value, but getting wrong output.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} {if ($5=="INV"){ getline; min=$6;max=$6}}
          {(min>$6)?min=$7:"";(max>$6)?"":max=$8}
     END{print min, max}' input.txt
```

Wrong output

```
IN27201800023182|
```

Comment: Honestly, expected output is not clear which you have shown, please be more clear on this one.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13.. I need to check identical rows from column 1 and need to find maximum and minimum from corresponding rowss of column6 and need to store max and min in column 8 and coluimn 7 respectively

Comment: Kindly provide more clear input and expected output in your post too now.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13...please check..updated my post..need output like this only..and please tell me whats wring with output..will clarify and update

Comment: what if there are different second column values?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzeled, how do you define the minimum of a string?

Answer (score 0):

This script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  OFS=FS="|";
  getline;
  saved=$1"|"$2; # saved for output
  min=substr($6,3); # initial min and max values
  max=substr($6,3);
}
{
  if ($5 == "INV") { # if column $5 is INC
    if (min > substr($6,3)) { min=substr($6,3); }; 
    if (max < substr($6,3)) { max=substr($6,3); }; 
  }
}
END{
  result=max-min+1;
  print saved,"","","IN"min,"IN"max,result,result;
}' \
input.txt
```

outputs:

```
27AAAC8C1ZZ|042018|||N27201800023182|IN27201800024289|1108|1108
```